# startlat = (double)((int)(SECornerLat * 100) / 100.0); // does not work for 33.73 but otherwise fine

Tags: c#, math, floor

I want to have a double with only two digits after the decimal point

```
startlat = (double)((int)(SECornerLat * 100) / 100.0);
```

if `SECornerLat` is equal to 33.73 then `startlat` will be 33.72.

I tried a multiple other numbers it works fine but it returns the wrong number with 33.73.

```
same thing in Floor(33.73*100)/100.
```

Comment: It won't work for many values, this is because the expectation of "work" is wrong wrt what is actually happening. (That is, the operation should be explained in more detail.)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

Comment: READ http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: 7-isnotbad has the answer it is a problem with precision rounding large numbers on a floating point - there has to be a point where the round falls to the not correct number.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
Double startlat = ((int) Math.Round((SECornerLat * 100), 0) / 100.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
startlat = (double)((33.73 * 100) / 100.0);
```